# How to /unregister a custom view (from xml) automatically on a bus

Tags: android, bus, registering

I have a custom EditText View. It extends the default one and adds the ability to show a TimePickerDialogFragment, a NumberPickerDialogFragment and similar...

All my FragmentDialogs are working with a bus system, to make the reattaching to the parent activity unneccessary...

Normally, I register all objects on creation and unregister them in the `onPause` of their parent activity... I use a scoped bus for that, which saves references to all registered objects and unregisters them automatically in the `onPause` of the activity. That work's optimal so far. All my custom classes use a constructor, which receive a reference to the scoped bus... So the class only has to register itself on the scoped bus and does not need to unregister itself anymore, the scoped bus will do that automatically.

Now registering my custom edittext is no problem, but how to automatically unregister it? I'm adding the views in XML and I don't want to have to add all of them manually to my scoped bus.

Does anyone have an idea how the unregistering could be somehow automated?

Comment: Are you implementing some interface to receive bus events or it is annotation based? In both cases you can onPause of your activity walk through children tree and unregister them if they implement interface or have annotated method.

Comment: But us for me views shouldn't know about bus from design point. Fragment or Activity should manage state of views based on event.

Comment: it is annotation based... I will consider using your idea and check, if the annotation method exists... just have to look how this can be done...

Comment: to the second point, what alternative would you suggest? My EditText will create a dialog and the dialog has to update the EditText (or rather more the corresponding edit text)...

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Otto. You could take a look how they are finding `@Subscribe` methods: https://github.com/square/otto/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/squareup/otto/AnnotatedHandlerFinder.java

From the design point of view (IMO) your view are mixing two responsibilities - some UI representation and communicating with lower system layers. The common sense rule - class is responsible for one thing only.

You can think about this from other point of view. It will be much harder to reuse such components in any project that doesn't use bus. Think about your internal design like you are going to open source your system components.

Comment: you are right, I'm mixing that a little bit. But I removed my interfaces because I decided to use the bus system, because for me it only has advantages... It makes my dialogs much easier... And of course, it is not reusable if it is not used with a bus, but on the other hand, it is much easier reusable if used with a bus... That actually was my decicion...

Comment: If keeping the bus (as I want to, because the positive points are much more important to me), do you have an idea how to solve the problem? Actually, I don't see another way as handling the bus event in the view class or handling the bus event in the main activity, with the disadvantage of having to somehow find the corresponding views in the bus event to update it... which has to be done in every activity manually...

Comment: Sure, some things are easier in your design for sure but disadvantages as well. For example this unsubscribing which requires you to write own base activities with quite complex onPause and onResume. There are not so many views in fragment or average activity so managing UI components on the event form model is preferred way for me

Comment: unsubscribing isn't that much work... I'm using a global ScopedBus with a map from an activity to an object list... (that is my solution now, which works quite good). I register/unregister in onResume/onPause and add/remove an activity in onCreate/onDestroy to keep the map clean... I'm using a base activity anyway, because I'm using custom animations on activity show/hide in my whole app... And I anyway found out, that a custom base activity can be quite helpful... some changes can be done really fast if you use it already...